# Пустая последовательность в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Ошибка:

```
  File "telegrambot.py", line 50, in send_message
    generate(message)
  File "telegrambot.py", line 155, in generate
    password += random.choice(uppercase_list + lowercase_list + digits_list + ''
.join(symbols_list))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py",
 line 290, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>
```

Код (не полностью):

```
for x in range(length):
    password += random.choice(uppercase_list + lowercase_list + digits_list + ''.join(symbols_list))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '`{0}`' .format(password), parse_mode="markdown")
```

Пытался исправить следующими кодами, но попытки не оказались удачными.

```
password += random.choice(''.join(uppercase_list) + ''.join(lowercase_list) + ''.join(digits_list) + ''.join(symbols_list))
```

```
global symbols_list

symbols_list = config.sl ( sl = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '?', '*', '(', ')', '{', '}', '~'] )

password += random.choice(''.join(uppercase_list) + ''.join(lowercase_list) + ''.join(digits_list) + ''.join(symbols_list))
```

Есть решение этой ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причиной этой ошибки был вот этот код:

```
if use_symbols == 'да':
    symbols_list = config.sl
else:
    symbols_list = ''
```

На всех остальных проверках было .lower()

```
if use_uppercase.lower() == 'да':
    uppercase_list = string.ascii_uppercase
else:
    uppercase_list = ''
if use_lowercase.lower() == 'да':
    lowercase_list = string.ascii_lowercase
else:
    lowercase_list = ''
if use_digits.lower() == 'да':
    digits_list = string.digits
else:
    digits_list = ''
if use_symbols == 'да':   <---------- здесь дописал .lower()
    symbols_list = config.sl
else:
    symbols_list = ''
```

Также, необходимо, чтобы в

```
random.choice(uppercase_list + lowercase_list + digits_list + ''.join(symbols_list))
```

было `''.join()`, потому что `symbols_list` это список.

Answer (score 0):

```
random.choice(uppercase_list + lowercase_list + digits_list + ''.join(symbols_list))
```

вот это `''.join(symbols_list)` - строка, а `uppercase_list, lowercase_list, digits_list` - список символов?

тогда как вы строку со списком складываете?

Comment: Переменной symbols_list присваивается sl = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '?', '*', '(', ')', '{', '}', '~'] с КОНФИГА, по необходимости если стоит Да или Нет.  ```if use_symbols == 'да':
  symbols_list = config.sl
 else:
  symbols_list = ''```

Comment: а вы можете просто сложить ваши списки без join и посмотреть (сделать Print) что в них - и потом уже choice делать, не надо их объединять в строку предварительно

Comment: Результат - https://prnt.sc/vpfiwb